# AngularJS instead of using two ng-show and two dropdowns Can I use one dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, html-select

**I want use 1 dropdown that need to satisfy both the conditions.**

```
<div ng-show="user == 'admin'">
     <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
         <select   ng-model="li"  >
             <option  ng-repeat="li in list">{{li.name}}</option>
         </select>
     </div> 
</div>

 <div ng-show="user != 'admin'">
     <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
         <select   ng-model="li"  >
             <option  ng-repeat="li in list|limitTo:1">{{li.name}}</option>
         </select>
    </div> 
</div>
```

[code in plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iDboEdVtm5qTM8KtKXm6?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
<div ng-if="user == 'admin'">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <select ng-model="li">
                <option  ng-repeat="li in list">{{li.name}}</option>
             </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="user != 'admin'">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <select ng-model="li">
                  <option  ng-repeat="li in list" ng-if="$first">{{li.name}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show` and use `ng-if="$first"` rather than putting `limitTo:1` filter.

Here is the updated plunker url:http://plnkr.co/edit/Cwc9prHQrULCKY8UmbSE?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

you can try filter

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.3"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
      app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
         $scope.user="admin";
          $scope.list = [
          {id:1,name:"first",tc:100},
          {id:2,name:"second",tc:103},
          {id:3,name:"third",tc:105}
        ]
        console.log("hi");
        console.log($scope.modes);
        $scope.filterrole=function(item){
          return $scope.user=="admin"?true:$scope.list[0]==item;
        }
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div >
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <select   ng-model="li"  >
                          <option value="">select {{user}}</option>
                            <option  ng-repeat="li in list |filter: filterrole">{{li.name}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div> 
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div><input type="button" value="admin" ng-click="user='admin'">
                    <input type="button" value="other" ng-click="user='other'"></div>
  </body>
</html>`
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/orL8oLOKSm7H4DJwXQyx?p=preview